# Bioformats-Python error: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb5' when using OMEXML()

Tags: python, xml, ascii, bioinformatics, biopython

I am trying to use bioformats in Python to read in a microscopy image (.lsm, .czi, .lif, you name it), print out the meta data, and display the image. `ome = bf.OMEXML(md)` gives me an error (below). I think it's talking about the information stored within `md`. It doesn't like that the information in `md` isn't all ASCII. But how do I overcome this problem?
This is what I wrote:

```
import Tkinter as Tk, tkFileDialog
import os
import javabridge as jv
import bioformats as bf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

jv.start_vm(class_path=bf.JARS, max_heap_size='12G')
```

User selects file to work with

```
#hiding root alllows file diaglog GUI to be shown without any other GUI elements
root = Tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_full_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
filepath, filename = os.path.split(file_full_path)
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(file_full_path))

print('opening:  %s' %filename)
reader = bf.ImageReader(file_full_path)
md = bf.get_omexml_metadata(file_full_path)
ome = bf.OMEXML(md)
```

Put image in numpy array

```
raw_data = []
    for z in range(iome.Pixels.get_SizeZ()):
    raw_image = reader.read(z=z, series=0, rescale=False)
    raw_data.append(raw_image)
raw_data = np.array(raw_data)
```

Show wanted metadata

```
iome = ome.image(0) # e.g. first image
print(iome.get_Name())
print(iome.Pixels.get_SizeX())
print(iome.Pixels.get_SizeY())
```

Here's the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-a22c1dbbdd1e> in <module>()
     11 reader = bf.ImageReader(file_full_path)
     12 md = bf.get_omexml_metadata(file_full_path)
---> 13 ome = bf.OMEXML(md)

/anaconda/envs/env2_bioformats/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bioformats/omexml.pyc in __init__(self, xml)
    318         if isinstance(xml, str):
    319             xml = xml.encode("utf-8")
--> 320         self.dom = ElementTree.ElementTree(ElementTree.fromstring(xml))
    321 
    322         # determine OME namespaces

<string> in XML(text)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb5' in position 1623: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here's a representative [test image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c22a5r4g2izdh4x/Cell1.lsm?dl=0) with proprietary microscopy format

Comment: Can you add upload one example image?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters, I just added a .lsm file for testing. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for adding the sample image. That helped tremendously!

Let's first remove all the unnecessary Tkinter code until we get to a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows us to reproduce your error message.

```
import javabridge as jv
import bioformats as bf

jv.start_vm(class_path=bf.JARS, max_heap_size='12G')

file_full_path = '/path/to/Cell1.lsm'

md = bf.get_omexml_metadata(file_full_path)

ome = bf.OMEXML(md)

jv.kill_vm()
```

We first get some warning messages about `3i SlideBook SlideBook6Reader library not found` but we [can apparently ignore](http://lists.openmicroscopy.org.uk/pipermail/ome-users/2015-October/005696.html) that.

Your error message reads `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb5' in position 1623: ordinal not in range(128)`, so let's look what we can find around position 1623.

If you add `print md` after `md = bf.get_omexml_metadata(file_full_path)`, the whole xml with metadata is printed out. Let's zoom in:

```
>>> print md[1604:1627]
PhysicalSizeXUnit="µm"
```

So, the `µ` character is the culprit, it can't be encoded with the `'ascii' codec`.

Looking back at the traceback:

```
/anaconda/envs/env2_bioformats/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bioformats/omexml.pyc in __init__(self, xml)
    318         if isinstance(xml, str):
    319             xml = xml.encode("utf-8")
--> 320         self.dom = ElementTree.ElementTree(ElementTree.fromstring(xml))
    321 
    322         # determine OME namespaces
```

We see that the in the lines before the error occurs, we encode our `xml` to `utf-8`, that should solve our problem. So why doesn't it happen?

if we add `print type(md)` we get back `<type 'unicode'>` and not `<type 'str'>` as the code expected.. So this is a bug in `omexml.py`!

To solve this, do the following (you might need to be root);

- Go to `/anaconda/envs/env2_bioformats/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bioformats/`
- remove  `omexml.pyc`
- in `omexml.py` change line 318 from `isinstance(xml, str):` to `if isinstance(xml, basestring):`

[`basestring`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#basestring) is the superclass for `str` and `unicode`. It is used to test whether an object is an instance of `str` or `unicode`.

I wanted to file a bug for this, but it seems there is already an [open issue](https://github.com/CellProfiler/python-bioformats/issues/55).